# Aptana Python 2.7 issues

Tags: python, windows, beautifulsoup, aptana, mechanize

I pulled a script from the net to see if everything was working fine before I start programming. I'm a noob and cannot figure out what is going on. I installed easy_install to smooth things, ironically.

I'm using Windows 7 64bit.

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013032300\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1397, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013032300\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1090, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\PythonScripts\PythonScripts\setupscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bs4\element.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\bs4\dammit.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: No module named html.entities
```

The Imports are:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! See: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation

For anybody else that may run into this issue, remove BS4 entry from `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packageseasy_install.pth`, then delete the BS4 folder and associated files.

Then run:

`easy_install beautifulsoup4` from CLI and remove the previous auto-config Python interpreter from Aptana Preferences > PyDev. Then re-add it and apply.